# Can I install 64-bit Eclipse on 32-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, application-development

I have 64 bit core i5 configuration I have installed ubuntu studio 11.04 (32 bit) on it.It's working fine but for eclipse android development it is not working what should I do? Should I download 64 bit eclipse or first I do have 64 bit studio OS and then install the rest development environment

Comment: Just for the benefit of people reading this later, why do you need 64-bit Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

No. You can install 32-bit software on an x64 bit machine but you can not install x64 based software on a 32-bit machine.

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/32-bit-and-64-bit-explained.htm

This rule applies to all Operating Systems.

Comment: First, install 64 bit OS. Then go for 64 bit Eclipse.

Comment: thank my machine was 64 bit and i installed 32 bit ubuntu studio and i m suffering in android development set up.............